# p5.js this._renderer.image is not a function issue

Tags: processing

```
var adobe1bar1;
function preload() {
  adobe1bar1 = loadImage("1-1.png");
}
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500, WEBGL);
  center = createVector(width / 2, height / 2, height / 2);
  cameraZ = -500;
}
function draw() {
  background(40); // backgraound white
  var cameraX = map(mouseX, 0, width, -500, 500); // map 
  var cameraY = map(mouseY, 0, height, -500, 500);
  console.log(cameraY, cameraX);
  if (cameraZ < -500) {
    cameraZ = -500;
  }
  if (cameraZ > 0) {
    cameraZ = 0;
  }
  camera(center.x + cameraX, center.y + cameraY, center.z + cameraZ, center.x, center.y, center.z, 0, 1, 0);
  translate(center.x, center.y, center.z);
  translate(0, 0, 0);
  image(adobe1bar1, -250, -250, 500, 500);
}
```

Here is my p5.js code.

When I use the `image() function`
The following error message keeps appearing.

> Uncaught TypeError: this._renderer.image is not a function

Is there a solution?

When not using 'WEBGL', 
it uploads images without error,
but the `camera()` function does not work.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the stack trace of the error in the console? It seems the error doesn't come from the code you posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

image is not a WEBGL function.

Try to apply an image texture to a plane instead.

```
texture(adobe1bar1);
translate(-250, -250, 0);
plane(500);
```

https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Getting-started-with-WebGL-in-p5

**EDIT:**
To use transparent texture you need to enable blend mode which can be done by using:

```
fill(0,0,0,0);
```

In setup

Comment: how can i use png image (transparent image) on texture()?

Comment: @JuneNan That sounds like a separate question. Please post it in a new question post along with an updated [mcve].